# Optimizing over 3 dimensional piece-wise constant function

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

I'm working on a simulation project with a 3-dimensional piece-wise constant function, and I'm trying to find the inputs that maximize the output. Using `optim()` in **R** with the `Nelder-Mead` or `SANN` algorithms seems best (they don't require the function to be differentiable), but I'm finding that `optim()` ends up returning my starting value exactly. This starting value was obtained using a grid search, so it's likely reasonably good, but I'd be surprised if it was the exact peak.

I suspect that `optim()` is not testing points far enough out from the initial guess, leading to a situation where all tested points give the same output.

1. Is this a reasonable concern?
2. How can I tweak the breadth of values that `optim()` is testing as it searches?

Comment: What makes you think that you can do any better than a grid search, without any continuity/differentiability conditions on the function? Do you have some other constraint available supplying local regularity conditions?

Comment: The issue with the grid search is the computational time involved (about 3 hours per simulation scenario). The grid search that I used spanned a broad range of inputs, with the goal of (a) visualizing overall pattern, and (b) finding generally where the optimal point lay. My hope with optim() was to refine the crude estimate of the optimal point in a consistent way that wouldn't require hours to run.

Comment: But I suppose I could just do a refined grid search around the "crude optimum" and see how that does.

Comment: If evaluating a single point takes 3 hours, you are in a lot of trouble no matter what.

Comment: Haha, yes. Testing 5 million points takes three hours.